# How do I find all all the subgroups of a group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

I'm failing to see the logic behind what makes up a subgroup. I understand the requirements of a subgroup (associativity, identity etc....) but I don't actually know how to find the subgroups.

I think it has something to do with "getting back to the identity", but I may be wrong? I know that the identity is a subgroup and the whole group is a subgroup. That's all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: associativity is not one of the requirements of a subgroup.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft depends on ones definition of subgroup.

Comment: @quid I don't see any way to define what a subgroup is where associativity cannot be removed.

Comment: It would help if you told us what your understanding of a "group" is, to gauge what you want to know about subgroups. It seems like you might be having more of a problem with the notion of "group" than with the notion of "subgroup."

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Redundancy exists. It is certainly trivial to *show* that a subset closed etc. also has associativity, but one might want to define with the property the a subgroup is a subset closed under the operations which is a group, and then prove that being non-empty and closed under operations $a,b\to ab$ and $a\to a^{-1}$ is enough.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft a subgroup of a group is a subset that is a group with respect to the inherited law. If you expand this, you get associativity as condition. (Yes, it's always associative, but formally the requirement is there, and I am nor sure OP is helped by being told assoc is not a requirement since it is prone to be misunderstood.)

Comment: There is generally no easy way to find all the subgroups of a group.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I got confused with something else. I understand what a group is and that the "associative-ness" of the subgroup is inherited from the group. My problem is finding what is in the subgroups.

Comment: @juanarroyo Okay, how would you usually go about it?

Comment: It would help to have a specific example, because the general problem of finding all subgroups is mathematically hard. Most intro courses use examples that are somewhat easy, but they need to be considered on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: For example the subgroups of Z20 (subscript 20), I understand they are {0},{0,5,10,15},{0,4,8,12,16},{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18} and the whole group. But, why? Why are these the only subgroups and how did they come about? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ see [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508770/for-group-mathbbz-18-how-do-i-find-all-subgroups?rq=1); take $20$ for $18$ there.

Comment: The first thing I look at is the order of the group.  The order of any subgroup must divide the order of the group.  So, if our group is $\mathbb Z_20^+$  The group has order 20.  The non trivial subgroups have order $2,4,5,10$  Now, we look for a subgroup of each order. $\{0,10\}$ would be one such subgroup.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies and the referral! I think I'm starting to understand it a bit better. @DougM why is {0,10} a subgroup, but say, {0,2} isn't? Does this have something to do with the order of the elements in the subgroup?

Comment: You can use $2$ to generate a subgroup.  The indetity ($0$ in this case) is in every subgroup.  If $2$ is in the subgroup then so is $2+2, 2+2+2,$ etc. because the subgroup must be closed under addition.  And, quickly enough you find a subgroup $\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18\}$

Comment: @DougM Ah I get it now! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 9):

The most basic way to figure out subgroups is to take a subset of the elements, and then find all products of powers of those elements.

So, say you have two elements $a,b$ in your group, then you need to consider all strings of $a,b$, yielding $$1,a,b,a^2,ab,ba,b^2,a^3,aba,ba^2,a^2b,ab^2,bab,b^3,...$$

If your group is not finite, you also have to consider negative powers. Or you can start with three members.

For abelian groups, it becomes simpler - you can take any:

$$a^nb^m$$

with $n,m$ integers, because $ab=ba$.

The simplest is to start with one elements: $\langle a\rangle=\{1,a,a^2,a^3,\dots\}$ is a subgroup for any $a$ if $G$ is finite, otherwise, you need to take $\{1,a,a^{-1},a^2,a^{-2},\dots\}$. In the case of cyclic groups, these are all the subgroups (although you get duplicates - there are $a\neq b$ such that $\langle a\rangle = \langle b\rangle$.)

Ultimately, you build from these, but in the general case, we are talking a hard problem.

You eventually learn to do certain types of deductions, but you should really try this brute force technique and use the understandings you have of the individual groups to forge ahead.

Comment: Great trick for solving beginner exercises

Answer (score 8):

Edit: Written this assuming you've taken a course on group theory.

Finding *all* subgroups of large finite groups is in general a very difficult problem. Usually, I'd start with [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory)) to find possible orders of subgroups.

Next, you know that every subgroup has to contain the identity element. Then you can start to work out orders of elements contained in possible subgroups - again noting that orders of elements need to divide the order of the group.

Since you've added the tag for cyclic groups I'll give an example that contains cyclic groups.

Consider the dihedral group $D_n = \langle r,s \mid r^n = s^2 = e, srs = r^{-1} \rangle$ where $e$ is the identity. It has order $2n$ and so the order of subgroups must divide $2n$. 
One such example is the subgroup $\langle r\rangle =  e, r, r^2, r^3, ..., r^{n-1} $ which is clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Answer (score 4):

The question is very hard in general, so one may want to consider some examples. Almost all popular examples have been discussed here at MSE; a starter is to find all subgroups of the group of units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for various $n$; see for example this question: [For group $\mathbb{Z_{18}^*}$, how do I find all subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508770/for-group-mathbbz-18-how-do-i-find-all-subgroups?rq=1). For more demanding examples one has to do more. A nice example is to find all subgroups of $S_6$, which are
$$ D_6, D_3, D_2, Z_6, Z_3, Z_2, D_3\times D_3, Z_3×Z_3, (Z_3\times Z_3)⋊ Z_2,
D_3 \times Z_3, Z_2 \times Z_2 \times Z_2, D_3 ≀ Z_2, Z_4, Z_5, D_4, Z_2 \times Z_4, D_4, D_5, A_4, D_4 \times Z_2, Z_5 ⋊ Z_4,
A_4 \times Z_2, S_4, (Z_3 \times Z_3) ⋊ Z_4, S_4 \times Z_2, A_5, S_5, A_6, S_6 $$
This has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446097/subgroups-of-s-6).

Also instructive is to study subgroups of matrices in $GL_n(K)$, for example the subgroup $SL_n(K)$ of invertible $n\times n$-matrices with determinant $1$, or $O_n(K)$ the subgroup of orthogonal matrices, or $Sp_n(K)$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy's Theorem may be more useful than Lagrange's Theorem, when dealing with finite groups. Cauchy's Theorem states that for every prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, there exists a subgroup $H \leq G$ of order $p$. So start with the cyclic subgroups of prime order. Then for any two cyclic groups $H_{1}, H_{2}$ of prime order, you can obtain a new subgroup by taking the join $\langle H_{1}, H_{2} \rangle$, which is the subgroup generated by the elements of $H_{1} \cup H_{2}$.

Now the subgroups of a group $G$ are ordered by the subgroup relation, which is a partial order. That is, the subgroup relation is reflexive (a group is a subgroup of itself), transitive (if $H \leq K$ and $K \leq M$, then $H \leq M$), and anti-symmetric (if $H \leq K$ and $K \leq H$, then $H \cong K$). So if you have two subgroups $H, K \leq G$ such that $H \not \leq K$ and $K \not \leq H$, the join $\langle H, K \rangle$ is another subgroup of $G$. Chapter 2, Section 5 in Dummit and Foote has a good exposition on the Lattice of Subgroups, which provides a visual graph called a Hasse Diagram to help study the subgroup partial order. I would direct you there for more reading.

Comment: Once you have Cauchy, you might as well also add Sylow.